# Update Panel in web part not working in Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have written a visual web part for SharePoint 2013 in VS2015. The web part contains a number of asp controls as well as a grid view. I implemented AJAX with using script manager proxy and update panel. The deployed web part works well in IE but in google chrome, it doesn't work. I have found the solution on the internet. http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2011/11/update-panel-not-working-in-google.html. I have put the code in js file in layout folder. In scriptmanager add reference to the file Path="/_layouts/15/prj/WebKit.js". However, it is not working in chrome. Could anyone please tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with SharePoint + UpdatePanel.
I've had the same problem and found the following article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx

To be honest, I couldn't apply the proposed solution, because I couldn't find the requested dll.

So, to solve my postback problem, I saw two possibilities: 
 1. Use DevExpress
 2. Change my code to client side.

I chose the second option.